# How do I implement Poincaré Embeddings using tfa.layers.PoincareNormalize?

Tags: python, tensorflow, embedding, hyperbolic-function

I am trying to implement Poincaré embeddings as discussed in a paper by Facebook ([Link](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08039.pdf)) for my hierarchical data. You may find a more accessible explanation of Poincaré embeddings [here](https://medium.com/@srijithpoduval/explaining-poincar%C3%A9-embeddings-d7cb9e4a2bbf).

Based on the paper I have found some implementations for Tensorflow [here](https://github.com/kousun12/tf_hyperbolic) and [here](https://github.com/qiangsiwei/poincare_embedding) as well as [tfa.layers.PoincareNormalize](https://www.tensorflow.org/addons/api_docs/python/tfa/layers/PoincareNormalize) in Tensorflow Addons. The latter even had a link to the paper mentioned above, which makes me believe it could be a good starting point for me. However, I had no luck implementing tfa.layers.PoincareNormalize so far and also could not find any documentation except some generic information on the API page that I linked.

Does anyone know how this layer is supposed to be implemented to provide the embedding in hyperbolic space discussed in the paper? My starting point is an implementation with a standard Embedding layer as presented below (it is actually an entity embedding of a categorical variable)?

```
input = Input(shape=(1, ))
model = Embedding(input_dim=my_input_dim, 
                    output_dim=embed_dim, name="my_feature")(input)
model = Reshape(target_shape=(embed_dim, ))(model)
model = Dense(1)(model)
model = Activation('sigmoid')(model)
```

Simply replacing the Embedding layer by tfa.layers.PoincareNormalize does not work due to different inputs. I assume that it could be placed somwhere after the embedding layer so that for the back propagation step the "values" are projected into hyperbolic space on each iteration, but had no luck with that so far either.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### Poincaré Embeddings

> However, while complex symbolic datasets often exhibit a latent hierarchical structure, state-of-the-art methods typically learn embeddings in Euclidean vector spaces, which do not account for this property. For this purpose, we introduce a new approach for learning hierarchical representations of symbolic data by embedding them into hyperbolic space – or more precisely into an n-dimensional Poincaré ball.

Poincaré embeddings allow you to create hierarchical embeddings in a non-euclidean space. The vectors on the outside of the Poincaré ball are lower in hierarchy compared to the ones in the center.

[image]

The transformation to map a Euclidean metric tensor to a Riemannian metric tensor is an open d-dimensional unit ball.

[image]

Distances between 2 vectors in this non-euclidean space are calculated as

[image]

The [research paper for Poincaré embeddings](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1705.08039.pdf) is wonderfully written and you will find some wonderful implementations in popular libraries for them as well. Needless to say, they are under-rated.

Two implementations that you can use are found in -

- `tensorflow_addons.PoincareNormalize`
- `gensim.models.poincare`

#### Tensorflow Addons implementation

According to the documentation, for a 1D tensor, `tfa.layers.PoincareNormalize` computes the following output along axis=0.

```
          (x * (1 - epsilon)) / ||x||     if ||x|| > 1 - epsilon
output =
           x                              otherwise
```

For a higher dimensional tensor, it independently normalizes each 1-D slice along the **dimension axis**.

This transformation can be simply applied to an embedding of n-dims. Let's create a 5 dim embedding for each element of the time series. The dimension axis=-1 in this case, which is mapped from a euclidean space to a non-euclidean space.

```
from tensorflow.keras import layers, Model, utils
import tensorflow_addons as tfa

X = np.random.random((100,10))
y = np.random.random((100,))


inp = layers.Input((10,))
x = layers.Embedding(500, 5)(inp)
x = tfa.layers.PoincareNormalize(axis=-1)(x)  #<-------
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
out = layers.Dense(1)(x)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='binary_crossentropy')
utils.plot_model(model, show_shapes=True, show_layer_names=False)

model.fit(X, y, epochs=3)
```

```
Epoch 1/3
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 7.9455
Epoch 2/3
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 7.5753
Epoch 3/3
4/4 [==============================] - 0s 2ms/step - loss: 7.2429
<tensorflow.python.keras.callbacks.History at 0x7fbb14595310>
```

#### Gensim implementation

Another implementation Poincare embeddings can be found in Gensim. Its very similar to what you would use when working with Word2Vec from Gensim.

The process would be -

1. Train Gensim embeddings (word2vec or poincare)
2. Initialize Embedding layer in Keras with embeddings
3. Set the embedding layer as non-trainable
4. Train model for the downstream task

```
from gensim.models.poincare import PoincareModel

relations = [('kangaroo', 'marsupial'), ('kangaroo', 'mammal'), ('gib', 'cat'), ('cow', 'mammal'), ('cat','pet')]

model = PoincareModel(relations, size = 2, negative = 2)  #Change size for higher dims
model.train(epochs=10)

print('kangroo vs marsupial:',model.kv.similarity('kangaroo','marsupial'))
print('gib vs mammal:', model.kv.similarity('gib','mammal'))

print('Embedding for Cat: ', model.kv['cat'])
```

```
kangroo vs marsupial: 0.9481239343527523
gib vs mammal: 0.5325816385250299

Embedding for Cat:  [0.22193988 0.0776986 ]
```

More details on training and saving Poincare embeddings can be found [here](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/poincare.html).